Trying to get data from an API endpoint, but keep getting errors even though I get data back when using Postman for example
I'm trying to get data from an API endpoint, but when I do
headers: new Headers(),

it gives an error about my request body, that the property is missing even tho I'm sending that property in the request.
When I add a header:
const headers = new Headers();

headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

headers: headers,

it gives the following errors see image below


This is what I found on another stack overflow question.
Cors Policy Question
Try adding this to your headers.
header.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
header.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS")
header.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With")

